# FileOutputStream creates a file, but FileInputStream

Tags: java, android, file, exception, fileinputstream

I am using a `FileOutputStream` to create a file in an activity that is not my `MainActivity`.  The file is created, and when I destroy the activity, the data I want is written, but when I relaunch the activity from my `MainActivity`, the file cannot be found.  What can I change in my code so that I don't get a `fileNotFoundException`?  The relevant code is here:

```
try {
 fis = new FileInputStream("words");
 ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
 fnfexception = e1;

} catch (IOException ioe) {
 ioe.printStackTrace();
}
EOFException eof = null;

int counter = 0;
if (fnfexception == null) {
 while (eof == null) {
  try {
   if (words == null) words = new Dict[1];
   else words = Arrays.copyOf(words, counter + 1);
   words[counter] = (Dict) ois.readObject();
   counter++;
  } catch (EOFException end) {
   eof = end;
  } catch (IOException ioe) {
   ioe.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
wordStartCount = counter;
wordCount = counter;
fnfexception = null;

try {
 fos = openFileOutput("words", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
 fnfexception = e1;

} catch (IOException ioe) {
 ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I don't think relative paths have any meaning in Android.

Comment: According to documentation, it does.  Google uses the following code:     String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();

Comment: This is different, because openFileOutput() opens a file in private app directory, and FileOutputStream creates a file in the file system, so it should be absolute.

Comment: Don't write code like this, with all the exception references. Code that depends on the success of code in a `try` block should be inside the same `try` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used wrong way to read from an internal file, use the following code

```
try {
    FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput("file_name");
    int content;
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    while ((content = fis.read()) != -1)
        str.append((char) content);
    fis.close();
    String savedText = str.toString();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Still get a FileNotFoundException

Comment: Make sure that you created the file without exceptions and you successfully wrote to it also make sure you use the same file name

Comment: I've already confirmed that it creates the file with no exceptions.

Comment: You might be using wrong file name, in my code I just used file_name, replace it with your own file name

Comment: yes, I mean in my code I used "file_name" as a file name. In yours, use "words" as it's the name you used to create the file